# Do I have to any settings when i install ldapsearch on rhel6?

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap

I want to install and use the ldapsearch on RHEL 6.8.
I will install with the command that "yum install ldapsearch".
Is that true?
Also can I use ldapsearch command after 'only' installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true. Use `yum provides "*/ldapsearch"` to see what package to install to get the `ldapsearch` binary.

You can use `ldapsearch` after 'only' installing if you have an LDAP server (on the same computer, or over a network connection) for it to connect to and search, you can't properly use it on its own.